# ¿Como puedo copiar este texto de Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

parece que con la ultima actualización de Android Studio algo a cambiado o desactivado, porque antes si podía seleccionar el texto que aparece en esa ventana y copiarlo con **CTRL + C**, pero ahora solo deja seleccionarlo y no puedo copiarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué hay que hacer para volver a copiar este texto?

O se puede configurar el teclado para personalizar esa opción?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Con `Alt + Intro (o Enter)` puedes hacer uso de una corrección rápida (`Control + F1`).

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia, estoy seleccionando el texto, y luego pulso Alt + Intro y no copia nada.

Comment: Vale, lo que quieres decir es para importar, pero eso no es lo que pregunto, esa ventana que se muestra, el texto se puede seleccionar, y luego copiar con **CTRL + C** para copiarlo al porta papeles, y luego pegarlo con **CTROL + V**, pero eso ya no funciona, si que se puede marchar o aleccionar el texto, pero no copiar.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que comentas es verdad, actualmente usando `Android Studio 3.5` o posterior, se puede ver la información y esta puede ser seleccionada pero **ya no puede ser copiada al "portapapeles"** mediante la secuencia <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Windows) .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, aunque no sé qué consiguen o qué ventajas tiene quietar esa posibilidad, los que no tenemos mucha idea de inglés, podíamos seleccionar el texto y luego traducirlo o bien hacer una búsqueda de ese error, hay posibilidad de activar alguna combinación de teclas en este apartado, como digo de inglés voy algo flojo y no sabría cual escoger de las opciones que hay en el apartado Keymap para intentar activar alguna combinación de teclas, si es que se puede hacer algo ahí. Mira la captura del primer post.

Comment: @SoCu En mi caso era muy útil para buscar información relacionada o copiar la información a algún compañero, ahora tengo que copiar la imagen y escribir el texto!!! :-( . Con respecto a la configuración Keymap, esta únicamente aplica para texto dentro de los archivos del proyecto.

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, esperaremos con los dedos cruzados a ver si esto vuelve a cambiar, o si alguien que se desenvuelva bien con el ingles le envía un correo a los señores diseñadores de Android Studio para recordarles que es bueno contar con poder copiar el texto de los cuadro de dialogo, si se llaman así.